# SceneBuilder2.0 does apply rules with color-lookup

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

When adding a .css file which contains a color-lookup to a scene in SceneBuilder2.0 (osx) the rules do not take effect.
The .css should change the background-color of a button using a color-lookup.
The lookup fails, the buttons background is transparent.

I added the .css as a Scene Style Sheet (Preview -> Scene Style Sheets -> Add a Style Sheet), which looks like this:

```
.root {
    abc: red;    
}

.button {   
    -fx-background-color: abc;   
}
```

The FXML looks like this:

```
<fx:root stylesheets="@supersimple.css" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
      <Button layoutX="270.0" layoutY="187.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

When loading the .fxml this Warning occurs:

> WARNING: Could not resolve 'abc' while resolving lookups for
>   '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.button' in stylesheet
>   supersimple.css

I also tried to apply a different .css for the rood node (an AnchorPane)

```
.pane {
    abc: red;    
}

.button {   
    -fx-background-color: abc;   
}
```

The behaviour stays the same: warning and transparent button background.

The lookup for "abc" fails, but why?
How can i make this work?

It would be necessary to have a proper preview in SceneBuilder.

Loading the fxml/css in an Application results in a proper red background for the button though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MoC on oracle-forum pointed out a workaround:

adding styleClass "root" to the root-pane does resolve the lookup-problem in SceneBuilder.

working FXML look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>  
<?import java.lang.*?>  
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>  
<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="root" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">  
   <children>  
      <Button layoutX="254.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />  
   </children>  
</fx:root>
```

see original post here:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3573420